# Expm in python and matlab

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am looking for  equivalent of Matlab's expm() function in python. Can someone help me?
Here is the Matlab explanation for the expm() function.

https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/expm.html

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the python equivalent is `scipy.linalg.expm`

See scipy documentation:
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.expm.html

The following code replicates the Matlab example given in your link to the documentation.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.linalg import expm

A = np.array([[1, 1, 0], [0, 0, 2], [0, 0, -1]])

expm(A)
```

```
Out[3]: 
array([[2.71828183, 1.71828183, 1.08616127],
       [0.        , 1.        , 1.26424112],
       [0.        , 0.        , 0.36787944]])
```

Comment: God bless you :)